# Show shortcodes as text without executing them

Tags: wordpress, backquote

Shortcode example: `[mytab] my content [/mytab]`.

But when the plugin is active, it shows the content of shortcode, not show the shortcode as text. I do not want to show the content, I want to show only the shortcode like this. `[mytab] my content [/mytab]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer from [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64616/133553):

3 solutions to show your shortcode as text ( not execute it ):

1. Use second `[]` for your shortcodes. Such as:

   ```
   [[my-shortcode]]
   ```

   For your case this solution will work so:

   ```
   [[mytab] my content [/mytab]]
   ```
2. Break the shortcode with some HTML tag, like `<span>`, `<p>`, `<code>`, `<div>` and etc. Such as:

   ```
   [<code>my-shortcode</code>]
   ```

   Your case:

   ```
   [<code>mytab</code>] my content [<code>/mytab</code>]
   ```
3. Escape `[` with `&#91;` and `]` with `&#93;`:

   ```
   &#91;my-shortcode&#93;
   ```

   Your code:

   ```
   &#91;mytab&#93; my content &#91;/mytab&#93;
   ```

   **NOTE:** if you'll add the 3-rd solution into Text Editor of WordPress and after will switch to Visual editor, then your escapes will converted to `[]`